# Significato di "lorda" in questo passaggio

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Per passare il tempo, Vita scarabocchiò il quaderno, e pensò a Cichitto libero come un gatto, che a quell’ora saliva da Lena a portare le rose, e Lena gli offriva un bicchiere di latte, e gli lavava la faccia, infilando pure i suoi vestiti incrostati di **lorda** nel mastello dei bordanti – che se Agnello lo fosse venuto a sapere la pestava – e poi se ne andava vagando per la città, senza essere trascinato a scuola con la forza, perché era figlio di nessuno e nessuno gli dava il tormento.

Ho trovato il termine ["lorda" sul *Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI09/GDLI_09_ocr_225.pdf&parola=l%C3%B3rda). Tuttavia, nessuna delle accezioni che si trovano là sembrano avere senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di questo vocabolo nel passaggio precedente? Non so se possa trattarsi di una voce di uso regionale.

Comment: Pensa che in dialetto ligure la _lurda_ o _lurdun_ vuole dire schiaffone... Nel contesto da te citato sembra voler significare sporcizia, sudiciume.

Comment: Una parola simile a lorda è [_lordura_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lordura/), derivata da lordo, che significa materia sudicia, che rende lordo, che imbratta sozzamente.

Answer (score 1):

Effettivamente i significati di lorda che si trovano in rete non si adattano al contesto da te citato.

Un termine che deriva sempre da lordo e si adatta nel tuo caso è [lordura](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lordura/), che significa materia sudicia, che rende lordo, che imbratta sozzamente.

> **lordura** s. f. [der. di lordo]. – Condizione, aspetto di ciò che è
>   lordo: la l. di quell’immondo locale è indescrivibile. Concr., materia
>   sudicia, che rende lordo, che imbratta sozzamente: *vicoli bui e pieni
>   di lordura; per lo viso gittandogli chi una l. e chi un’altra*
>   (Boccaccio).

Answer (score 0):

Una possibilità potrebbe essere un refuso del testo: “lorda” con una “i” mancante.

Il termine “lordìa” al sud è utilizzato come sinonimo di lordura.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!